# Ubuntu 12.10 Crashing Compiz/Unity (not Nvidia related)

Tags: unity, compiz, 12.10

I've upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 and compiz and/or unity are constantly crashing rendering my computer useless (no top bar, no dash, no window decorations). I have just discovered that when I login with the guest account everything seems to be working OK.

I've been through all the threads I could find and haven't found a resolution. This isn't Nvidia related (I am running on a System76 laptop with ATI Radeon).

Is there any way I can go about isolating the problem and restore my user account?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3):

<del>Try typing `unity --reset` in a terminal.</del>

I discovered that this command doesn't work any longer but there's another way to reset Unity.

First of all install dconf-tools: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
Then to reset Unity and Compiz:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

followed by

```
setsid unity
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Typing `unity --reset` in a terminal yields `ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated`

Comment: and how to reach the terminal without unity, would you tell us??

Comment: CTRL + ALT + F1. CTRL + ALT + F7 to return to graphical mode.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the related issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/1069199